# addImageToMediaGallery creates two image entries while having only one file

Tags: magento-1.9, product, import, product-images, programmatically

What I've done:

- I've imported all my products once (without any problems regarding the images)
- Deleted all of them and then deleted all files under media/catalog/products
- imported all my products again

  - Now it creates two image entries in my product while only the first exists

    - 1234.jpg *(only this file exists)*
    - 1234_1.jpg **(selected as default)**

So i assume there is an cache, db entry, something which remembers the file which was there at some point.

Line which triggers the image import:
`$this->product->addImageToMediaGallery($this->filepath, array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'), true, false);`

Comment: You deleted all files in media/products or in media/catalog/product ?

Comment: My fault deleted catalog/product of course

Comment: If you have followed all the above steps in same order, check in admin configuration, if media folder is mapped somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this answer - [addImageToMediaGallery and getMediaGalleryImages](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/135230/addimagetomediagallery-and-getmediagalleryimages)
You might be saving the product multiple times, after each addImageToMediaGallery call. In this case, duplicate image paths (the ones with '_1' appended) will be created and added to the product, without the files actually being there. Moving product->save outside of any loop should help avoid this.