# addImageToMediaGallery and getMediaGalleryImages

Tags: magento-1.9

I've been working on a batch interface for clients to be able to create products programatically on Magento, which is working well. I've got images uploading into the media/import folder and then being imported into Magento with the following code;

```
<?php $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($entity);?>
  <?php if(file_exists($path."/".$filename)):?>
    <?php $product->addImageToMediaGallery($path."/".$filename, array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'), false, false);?>
    <?php $gallery = $product->getData('media_gallery');?>
    <?php $lastImage = array_pop($gallery['images']);?>
    <?php $lastImage['label'] = $name;?>
    <?php array_push($gallery['images'], $lastImage);?>
    <?php $product->setData('media_gallery', $gallery);?>
    <?php $product->setData('has_images','1');?>
    <?php $product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product,'has_images');?>
    <?php $product->save();?>
  <?php endif;?>
```

This was based on a mixture of solutions from a few users, and seems to correctly import the files into the storage system with automatic appending of numerics on duplicate filenames.

The only problem I get is that by then calling the images back using the following code, images added via the script are ignored and I'm really not sure why!

```
<?php foreach($product->getMediaGalleryImages() as $image):?>
  <img src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'image', $image->getFile())->resize(100, 100); ?>"/>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Comment: figured it out, in order for the images to be registered, the product must first have a blank image array saved, pushing an item into the array saves it correctly for the product to work, but doesn't update the internal image index.

Answer (score 2):

When creating the product you MUST add a blank array for images, otherwise the image index for the product will not be updated when adding via script.

```
 ->setMediaGallery (array('images'=>array (), 'values'=>array ()))
```